# How do I avoid duplicate labels in C3JS

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I have a graph in C3JS and i was trying to avoid duplicate labels. When I have a large range of data it does not duplicate the labels but with a small range of data it does.
How do I have it so that it will only display the numbers 19-23% in this case.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:- Use axis.tick.limit config set to lesser value like 4 or 5, so that less number of tick values are shown.

Solution 2:- Set axis.tick.format config to a function, which returns percentages a rational number like 20.0%, 20.5%, 21.0%, 21.5%, etc.

Second solution is better.

From the additional y axis labels, it looks like you have already overridden the format function, Just make sure it returns percentages with decimals.

```
axis: {
    y2: {
        tick: {
            count:3,  // Limit number of axis ticks (solution 1)
            format: function(d){//logic to return formatted percentages with decimal digit}
        }
    }
}
```